# Confusion on polar coordinates of an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, polar-coordinates

[image]

The polar coordinates of an ellipse are given by:
$$x=\frac{abcos(\theta)}{\sqrt{b^2cos^2(\theta)+a^2sin^2(\theta)}}$$

$$y=\frac{absin(\theta)}{\sqrt{b^2cos^2(\theta)+a^2sin^2(\theta)}}$$

However, I have often seen the following being used in my textbook and other places:
$$x=acos(\theta)$$
$$y=bsin(\theta)$$

Are these two forms the same? Is there something I'm unable to see? Or are there two ways to explain the coordinates of an ellipse?

Comment: More often, people seem to prefer a focus as the center of the polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical equation for ellipse is:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

Check and see that both of these parametrizations satisfy the equation. So they both are correct in that sense.

But the angle dependense is not the same in two cases, meaning the first one is not the usual polar coordinate system.

For example, set $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$, you will get:

$$x=y=\frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$$

in the first case and:

$$x=\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}$$

$$y=\frac{b}{\sqrt{2}}$$

in the second case.

Comment: Oh, OK got it. Would it be correct if I understood the first as projections of the radius and the second as fractions of the total lengths of the semi axes?

Comment: Also, in the second case, the angle is not the one I drew in the diagram, right?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. Just name it a different letter, like $\phi$, then try to solve the equations $x(\phi)=x(\theta)$ and the same for $y$. You will figure out the relationship between these angles